# Change button text smoothly

Tags: java, android, button

Is there any way to animate the changing text of a button.

Currently I'm using `button.setText("string");`

I want the button text to change smoothly when I call the `setText()` in a code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want a smooth transition like **Fade Out** and **Fade In** while switching text, you can create a method like this. This will change the text with fade animation.

```
  private void setTextWithSmoothAnimation(TextView textView, String message) {
        textView.animate().setDuration(300).setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

            }


            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                textView.setText(message);
                textView.animate().setListener(null).setDuration(300).alpha(1);
            }


            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

            }


            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

            }
        }).alpha(0);
    }
```

As you are using **Button**, you will need to **replace the Button with TextView and surrounding this TextView with any LinearLayout or FrameLayout**. After that, you will need to provide the background to the layout.